# Create a program that allows you to perform the depth first search traversal and breadth first search traversal

Tags: graph, traversal

Create a program that allows you to perform the depth first search/traversal as
well as the breadth first search/traversal on the following graphs:

1. Perform Depth First Traversal
2. Perform Breadth Fist Traversal
3. Search Graph 1(DFS)
4. Search Graph 2(BFS)
5. Exit

[image]

1. When the user chooses [1], the user is asked which graph he or she wants to
   traverse. The program then prints out the final order in which the nodes are
   visited using the Depth First Traversal.
2. When the user chooses [2], the user is asked which graph he or she wants to
   traverse. The program then prints out the final order in which the nodes are
   visited using the Breadth First Traversal.
3. Choosing [3] searches for the vertex inputted by the user. Use the DFS on
   Graph 1 and print a message if the vertex is not part of the graph.
4. Choosing [4] searches for the vertex inputted by the user. Use the BFS on
   Graph 2 and print a message if the vertex is not part of the graph.
5. Keep on displaying the menu until the user chooses [5].
6. Implement the graph using an adjacency matrix*.

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Those in numbers were the questions.

Comment: Those aren't questions. Those are instructions.